# c# method with variable number of generic parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, generic-programming, ebay-api

I'm trying to work with ebay Api, They say you should only at max 18 threads
for processing requests + Handle retries.

So I'm trying to make a wrapper that will execute all my ebay commands.

the problem is that I have a lot of different types of requests to ebay, with different number of parameters, So I'm trying to understand how to send them all to my wrapper and get the result I need.

Maybe this is not the best way to accomplish this at all, I'm un certain about how to implement this.

```
private static SemaphoreSlim sem = new SemaphoreSlim(18);
private static int retryCount = 2;

public static async Task<T> RunTask<T, V>(Func<V, T> ebayAction, V param1)
{
  // Wait the semaphore.
  await sem.WaitAsync();
  int currentRetry = 0;
  for (; ; )
  {
    try
    {
      // If response failed try again.
      return await Task.Run(() => ebayAction(param1));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      currentRetry++;
      if (currentRetry >= retryCount)
      {
        throw e;
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      sem.Release();
    }
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
private List<ProductData> SearchItems(string keyword)
{
  return EbayApiRequestFactory.Create<EbayFindApiRequest>()
    .SetKeyword(keyword)
    .SetEntriesLimit(100)
    .Execute().Result;
}

List<ProductData> searchProducts = await EbayHandler.RunTask(SearchItems, keyword);
```

Comment: `Func<T> ebayAction`, `EbayHandler.RunTask(() => SearchItems(keyword))`.

Comment: If you're trying to limit simultaneous requests, why not make a handler for HttpClient with a semaphore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change your wrapper signature as follows:

```
async Task<TResult> RunTask<TResult>(Func<TResult> ebayAction)
```

And run it as

```
RunTask(() => SearchItems(keyword));
```

If you have another method with another number of arguments:

```
RunTask(() => SearchItems(keyword, argument2, argument3));
```

You can add more overloads if necessary, like:

```
// some action which does not return result
static async Task RunTask(Action ebayAction)
// some function which is already asynchronous so you don't need
// to wrap it into Task.Run
static async Task<TResult> RunTask<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> ebayAction)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I made such a mess of things, I tried something similar before but I think the parameters I sent to the wrapper were out of context so It didn't work at the time.